# print uneven list of lists in columns with python

Tags: python-3.x, list, format, multiple-columns

I have two lists

```
list1 = ['ipv6']
list2 = ['autodiscover', 'cdn0', 'dev', 'email', 'link', 'mail', 'shop', 'www']
```

Using the following print command and formatting I am trying to print the two lists in separate columns separated by the '|' character.

```
 print("{:<25} {:<1} {:<15}".format('\n'.join(list1), '|', '\n'.join(list2)))
```

The first item in each list properly aligned however all subsequent items from list2 are aligned to the left of the terminal.

```
Tags                      Subdomains
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv6                      | autodiscover
cdn0
dev
email
link
mail
shop
www
```

Using the standard Python3 modules (no 3rd party modules) how would I align the other items in the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26005077/1024832

Comment: All the examples had lists of same length, and several of the solutions used 3rd party modules like pandas, tableit, and tabulate. thanks for looking though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hacky if you don't want to use other libraries but it'll work if you pad `list1`:

```py
list1 = ['ipv6']
list2 = ['autodiscover', 'cdn0', 'dev', 'email', 'link', 'mail', 'shop', 'www']
pad = ['']*(len(list2)-len(list1))
for i,j in zip(list1+pad, list2):
    print(f"{i:<25} | {j:<15}")
```

Output:

```py
ipv6                      | autodiscover   
                          | cdn0           
                          | dev            
                          | email          
                          | link           
                          | mail           
                          | shop           
                          | www
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. I was able to have a properly aligned table with far less code than the route I was taking.